# Code tag is not working in angular html template

Tags: html, angular, angular2-template

I would like to display the below snippet in my html page. I'm using angular 2.

```
{path: 'test', component: TestComponent}
```

I've added below in my template to achieve this:

```
<pre>
<code>{path: 'test', component: TestComponent}</code>
</pre>
```

When I load the template, I see below error. How do I fix this? Can't I use code tag?

```
directive_normalizer.js:127 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an unescaped "{" in your template? Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape it.) ("
        </ngb-tab>
    </ngb-tabset>
</div>[ERROR ->]"): TestComponent@31:6
Invalid ICU message. Missing '}'. ("
        </ngb-tab>
    </ngb-tabset>
</div>[ERROR ->]"): TestComponent@31:6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error Message provides the solution. Do the following:

```
<pre>
<code>{{"{path: 'test', component: TestComponent}"}}</code>
</pre>
```

Through interpolation it returns a string with the content.

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me. So, the issue was angular because it got confused although it was inside code tag.

Answer (score 3):

Angular is trying to parse it as expression You have to escape the '{' braces as shown below.

```
<pre>
<code>{{'{'}}path: 'test', component: TestComponent{{'}'}}</code>
</pre>
```

Comment: I like this one - it is much easier to deal with code spanning multiple lines.